# How to access the expanded state of collapsiblepanel in javascript? (Richfaces 4.5.0.Final)

Tags: javascript, richfaces, jsf-2.2

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel id="panelId" expanded="false"
    switchType="ajax" header="Awesomeness" 
    onswitch="console.log('Expanded')">
    ------
    Some amazing content
    ------
</rich:collapsiblePanel>
```

How can I access the value of the expanded attribute inside the onswitch function using EL or Javascript? (I am using Richfaces 4.5.0.Final & JSF 2.2)

```
For eg:    onswitch="if(<panel is expanded>) {console.log('Expanded')}"
```

Comment: I have no richfaces knowledge (anymore) but I'd check for the presence of a 'class' first on the html (assuming there is no real api (which you can check in the javascript source))

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Nope Emil. Still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some JavaScript function from RF to check this in more elegant way, but this panel holds hidden input with information about current state (with id = panelId + "*-value*", here it's "*panelId-value*",  if you want to get this element somewhere else).

Just try:

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel id="panelId" expanded="false"
        switchType="ajax" header="Awesomeness"
        onswitch="console.log(this.children[0].value);">
    ------
    Some amazing content
    ------
</rich:collapsiblePanel>
```